# In c# win forms how do I scroll over hundreds of items

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a common design for allowing the user to scroll over hundreds or thousands of items in a windows forms container? Example: writing an email client, the user gets the impression of smoothly scrolling over 10,000 message "rows," one for each email - but those surely are not really rendered until just before they are displayed. Similarly, scrolling over a huge image must require tiling it in smaller pieces, but how is the code organized that presents that?

Comment: Look for information on MSDN for the ListView.VirtualMode property.  It manages this by raising an event that asks for item(s) in the displayed view by their index into the large array of items.

Comment: 3 Letter solution to your problem: [**WPF**](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/). It has built-in support for [UI Virtualization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA), and built in support for hardware acceleration, and many other features. winforms is only used to maintain legacy applications, and not recommended for any new projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned [VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx) is probably the best solution, there is a [usage example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42229/Virtual-Mode-ListView).

Initialize virtual mode on form creation:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.VirtualMode = true;       // switching virtual mode on
            listView1.VirtualListSize = 1000000000;     // give it 1 million lines
        }
```

then assign and handle `RetrieveVirtualItem` event:

```
private void listView1_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
   {
       ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();   // create a listviewitem object
       lvi.Text = nt.MakeText(e.ItemIndex);         // assign the text to the item
       ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(); // subitem
       NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat;
       nfi.NumberDecimalDigits = 0;
       lvsi.Text = e.ItemIndex.ToString("n", nfi);  // the subitem text
       lvi.SubItems.Add(lvsi);          // assign subitem to item

       e.Item = lvi;        // assign item to event argument's item-property
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

It is innate to the way Windows is designed and doesn't require 3 letters or special modes.

A GUI program, regardless of its flavor, gets messages from Windows whenever it is expected to perform an operation.  Messages are not processed in the order they are generated.  There are three basic "priorities":

- important messages are directly delivered, the underlying winapi function is SendMessage()
- user input is stored in a queue first, the underlying winapi function is PostMessage()
- certain messages are *synthesized* from the window state and are only generated when none of the two above message types need to be processed.

Messages are processed in the above order.  Sent messages go first, if none are pending then the program starts emptying the message queue.  If that's empty then the synthesized messages are dispatched.  Painting falls in the 3rd category.  A program only ever gets a WM_PAINT message when *nothing* else needs to be done.

So the basic chain of events is that the control retrieves a mouse message from the message queue and detects that it was meant for the scrollbar.  It calculates a new position for the scrollbar thumb and calls the InvalidateRect() winapi function to indicate that the window is need to be painted.  Same function as the Invalidate() method in Winforms.  The internal window state is updated to mark that a paint is needed to repaint that rectangle.  This is all very fast, no actual painting takes place.

Two basic things can now happen when the program retrieves the next message.  It might yet again be a mouse message as the user keeps scrolling.  Handled the exact same way as above, nothing happens to the window beyond a change to the thumb position.

Or there is no new message to be processed, the user stopped scrolling, and now the category #3 synthesized messages get a turn.  Windows notices that the window needs to be repainted and delivers the WM_PAINT message.

There are some implementation details beyond this, later versions of Windows have the "Show window contents while dragging" system option turned on by default.  Which makes it easier for the user to see what he's doing while dragging the thumb, it intentionally generates extra window paints.  All and all, having tens of thousands of items in a ListView is well supported by the operating system and your program.  Not by the user of course.